# Database Design to store various data source credentials

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, erd

I am currently working on a database to store Multiple user's API Credentials details. This will then be used to pull data based on these credentials. Each data source will have a different format for API credentials. Is there any best practice to store this. Should it be comma delimited, XML format? Also, should it be encrypted, if so how do I encrypt this.

Example:

```
Data Source 1 for Client 1 is Google Docs
Data Source 2 for Client 1 is Oracle Cloud 
Data Source 1 for Client 2 is PayPal
```

Both of these APIs will be consumed differently and will have different credentials that will be required.

Comment: Delimited text is probably the worst option. EAV is bad, but slightly better then delimited text, and XML is probably the lesser evil.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled do you have any other recommendation as to how it should be stored...?

Comment: No. We would need more information to answer.